# Automator - Launch terminal at certain folder

Tags: terminal, automator

Is there a way in Automator to open the terminal application at a certain folder location with 2 tabs at that location?

So for example open terminal with 2 tabs that have already changed directory from the root folder to `Documents/Websites`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Terminal** can be finicky beast when it comes to automation; however, with the use of **UI Scripting** the following *example* **AppleScript** *code* can be used in **Script Editor** and saved as an application, or in **Automator** in a **Run AppleScript** *action*.

Note that using **UI Scripting** may require [accessibility privileges](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/AutomatetheUserInterface.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016239-CH69-SW1) be granted.

<sup>This was tested and works under macOS High Sierra.</sup>

```
do shell script "open -a 'Terminal' ~/Documents/Websites"
tell application "Terminal" to activate
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "t" using {command down}
    keystroke tab using {control down, shift down}
end tell
```

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* above will open a new **Terminal** window to the specified location and then open a new tab to the same location while setting focus back to the first tab.

---

Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and does not contain any error handling as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any error handling as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.